# FirstOrDefaultAsync() & SingleOrDefaultAsync() vs FindAsync() EFCore

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-2.0

We have 3 different approaches to get  single items from EFCore they are `FirstOrDefaultAsync()`, `SingleOrDefaultAsync()` (including its versions with not default value returned, also we have `FindAsync()` and maybe more with the same purpose like `LastOrDefaultAsync()`.

```
var findItem = await dbContext.TodoItems
    .FindAsync(request.Id)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);

var firstItem = await dbContext.TodoItems
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == request.Id)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);

var singleItem = await dbContext.TodoItems
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == request.Id)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I would like to know the differences between each one of them. So far what I know is that we `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` to get the first given a condition, (usually using this because we know that more than one item can satisfy the condition), on the other hand we use  `SingleOrDefaultAsync()` because we know that there is only one possible match to find, and `FindAsync()` to get an item given its primary key.

I think `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` & `SingleOrDefaultAsync()` always hit the database (not sure about this), and `FindAsync()` this is what Microsoft docs says:

> Asynchronously finds an entity with the given primary key values. If
> an entity with the given primary key values exists in the context,
> then it is returned immediately without making a request to the store.
> Otherwise, a request is made to the store for an entity with the given
> primary key values and this entity, if found, is attached to the
> context and returned. If no entity is found in the context or the
> store, then null is returned.

So my question is, if our given condition used for `FirstOrDefault()`, `SingleOrDefault()` and `FindAsync()` is the primary key, **do we have any actual difference?**

What I think is that the first time they are used always hit the db, **but what about the next calls?**. And probably EFCore could use the same context to get the values for `FirstOrDefault()` and `SingleOrDefault()` as it does for `FindAsync()`, **maybe?**.

Comment: They are all very different things and its spelled out in the documentation for all. there are several duplicates about this question, and also a lot of information online. `First` and `Single` will always hit the db, `Find` wont. also `First` and `Single` do different things as well. Which one you choose should be very obvious based on if there is only going to be one record, potentially more than one, or if you dont mind it being cached in the context

Comment: Do a database trace of the SQL being executed. As a general rule, `FirstOrDefault` will do a `TOP 1` and `SingleOrDefault` will do a `TOP 2` (i.e. be slightly slower).

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/4737 may be worth a read.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`FindAsync`

> In much of the scaffolded code, FindAsync can be used in place of
> FirstOrDefaultAsync.

`SingleOrDefaultAsync`

> fetches more data and does unnecessary work. throws an exception if
> There's more than one entity that fits the filter part.

`FirstOrDefaultAsync`

> doesn't throw if there's more than one entity that fits the filter
> part.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/crud?view=aspnetcore-2.2#singleordefaultasync-vs-firstordefaultasync

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, but it had been hard to find because is inside another article for Razor Pages.

Answer (score 24):

[FindAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.findasync?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContext_FindAsync_System_Type_System_Object___):

- Accepts primary key
- Optimized for finding an entity with a primary key, by returning the
  entity without hitting the database if the entity was tracked.
- Can't use the `include` method with FindAsync.
- Returns default value if no match was found.

[FirstOrDefaultAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.firstordefaultasync?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions_FirstOrDefaultAsync__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Threading_CancellationToken_):

- Accepts Expression.
- Better choice over FindAsync if related entities are needed.
- Returns default value if no match was found.

[SingleOrDefaultAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.singleordefaultasync?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions_SingleOrDefaultAsync__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0_System_Boolean___System_Threading_CancellationToken_):

- Accepts Expression.
- Returns default value if no match was found.
- Throws an exception if more than one match were found.